# How do you download new songs when "Show All Songs" is off?

Tags: ios, icloud, itunes-match

When you enable iTues Match, you have a "Show All Songs" option. When it's on, the label text states:

> All music that has been downloaded or that is stored in iCloud will be shown.

When you turn it off, the text changes to;

> Only music that has been downloaded to this device will be shown.

The extreme benefit of the latter change is that songs won't hang up when only part of an album has been downloaded and the player advances to an undownloaded song.

Is there another way to download music even if "Show All Music" is turned off?

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed this and sadly, I haven't found a way to enable it, I don't want to see every song on my iPhone either, just the ones I have downloaded.

If I want to listen to something not listed I have to change the setting back and then download, then change it back after downloading.

Alternatively you could (but at risk of wasting 1) Time and 2) Money) try these.

1. Plug the device into iTunes, or sync over a network
2. you can enable automatically download purchases to the iPhone

Comment: When iTunes Match is enabled, the music section of your device settings in iTunes disappears.

Comment: Never noticed that.